# Total type of CSV file

Tags: csv

I would like to ask there are how many types of csv.

Therefore, I have checked when I am going to save an Excel file.There are window comma seperated,ms dos comma seperated and normal csv. So far I have found these.

However, I could not find on google about the total types of csv. Maybe my keywords are wrong.May I know the rest other than those I have mentioned and their differences?

I will appreciate too if any link provided by you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an RFC document for CSV, [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), it is not strictly followed.

Other variants on CSV depend on how cells are quoted, no quotes, double quotes...

Some people treat lines with '#' as a comment.  Others do not.

Some have header rows, some don't.

Some places will even merge CSV data from multiple sources by concatenation and sorting on some column, and use the number of columns in a particular row to identify the record type.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will have a look and study. Appreciate.